# How to get all option id values before selecting in script

Tags: javascript, html, select

My code is:

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="store_in_right_side">
<option value="1">supby</option>
<option value="2">supby1</option>
<option value="3">supby2</option>
<option value="4">supby3</option>
</select>
```

In this how can i get all option id, when i submitting a button.,

Comment: _all option id_ ? What ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get selected value in dropdown list using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var allval = [];
$('select#search_to ').find('option').each(function() {
allval.push($(this).val());
});
```

use allval variable you get all values, else

```
    $('select#search_to ').find('option').each(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
    });
```